# calculating sale price based on dependent fees in python

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out what the sale price would be, for an item with a margin of 25%. However there are 2 variables that are dependent on the sale price to compute the price of that particular fee, as shown in the example below:

```
cost_price = 8.50 * 1.2

fee_1 = sale_price * 0.2
fee_2 = (sale_price * 0.066) + 0.60
fee_3 = 2.90
fee_4 = 0.20
cost = fee_1 + fee_2 + cost_price + fee_3 + fee_4

sale_price = cost / (1-0.25)

print(sale_price)
```

I get the following Error:

> ---
>
> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> ipython-input-5-2562b4009d70 in module()
>   1 cost_price = 8.50 * 1.2
>   2 
>   ----> 3 fee_1 = sale_price * 0.2
>         4 fee_2 = (sale_price * 0.034) + 0.20
>         5 fee_3 = 2.90
>
> NameError: name 'sale_price' is not defined

I am still new to programming in python, so any help would be greatly appreciated or a general direction as to where I could possibly head to, in order to arrive at the solution. Will continue working on this until resolved; will report back if I manage to solve the problem.

Comment: You are trying to use a variable that you define only later... i.e. you define `sale_price` in the last line before the `print` statement, but tries to use it in your second line. Why do you think that should work? ;}

Comment: @aslan Seems you really meant to use `cost_price` instead, try replacing all `sale_price` with `cost_price`.

Comment: Hi Rafael, if I declare teh sale_price before fee_1 I end up with an error for the cost and I am unable to work out the cost without fee_1 and 2..

Comment: @davedwards, the fee is dependent on the sale price, not the cost price unfortunately. Otherwise this would have made my life a whole lot easier :(

Comment: This is not really related to python programming, but to the logic. I do not know what you mean by `cost_price` or `sale_price` of `fee`, but there is something wrong in the way you define them. It is impossible to compute two variables if the former depends on the latter and viceversa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking strictly business, you can't calculate the fees you apply to a product/service based on the `sale_price`, as the `sale_price` already includes those fees. You'd be calculating a fee on top of that same fee, virtually doubling it.

All your fees must be calculated with regards to the `cost_price` or else you should arbitrarily define fee values to be added on top of it. This is how the code should look (as already answered by other people):

```py
cost_price = 8.50 * 1.2

fee_1 = cost_price * 0.2
fee_2 = (cost_price * 0.066) + 0.60
fee_3 = 2.90
fee_4 = 0.20
cost = fee_1 + fee_2 + cost_price + fee_3 + fee_4

sale_price = cost / (1-0.25)

print(sale_price)
```

**UPDATE:**

After new info, here's my take: `fee_1` and `fee_2` cannot be based on the `sale_price`, or else you gotta call `sale_price` something else. But naming aside, if you really want them to derive from the so called `sale_price`, here's how you could do it:

```py
cost_price = 8.50 * 1.2

fee_3 = 2.90
fee_4 = 0.20
cost = cost_price + fee_3 + fee_4

sale_price = cost / (1-0.25)  # line 7 -- btw, why not use 0.75 instead of 1 - 0.25?

# now that sale_price exists, we can generate the fees based on it
fee_1 = sale_price * 0.2
fee_2 = (sale_price * 0.066) + 0.60

sale_price += fee_1 + fee_2

print(sale_price)
```

However, I strongly advise against using this kind of logic, as it is not intuitive and can be very confusing. I believe you should, at the very least, rename your variables and call `sale_price` something like `partial_sale_price` on line 7.

Comment: Hi Luca, I had a feeling that may be the case, as for fee_1 and fee_2 they are based on sale_price.

I guess its back to the square one for me, Will have to try some sort of convergence method see if I have any luck with that.

Comment: @Aslan I've updated my answer, please check it out :)

Comment: Thats is very similar to what I have managed to achieve Luca! It is more of a convergence solution than an actual one, but a solution nevertheless. Thankyou so much for all your help =D

Comment: @Aslan Great, I'm glad you've reached a solution :) If my answer or any of the others has helped you solve your question, please remember to mark it as the correct answer, so people can refer to it in the future more easily :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared the variable `sale_price` anywhere. So the compiler doesn't know what to do next.

Did you mean to use `cost_price` instead?

Comment: Hi alex, that is the problem I am currently stuck at, the sale_price can only be computed if I have the values for fee_1 and fee_2, however I cannot work out fee_1 and fee_2 if I do not have the sale_price

Comment: Can you explain the logic of what you are trying to do?

Fee cannot depend on sales price if sales price depends on fee.

Comment: The logic is as follows:

I am trying to find out what price I should sell an item If I have the following:
(1) cost price (£8.50+VAT).
(2) fee 1 is 20% of the sale price.
(3) fee 2 is 6.6% of sale price + £0.60.
(4) fee 3 is £2.90.
(5) fee 4 is £0.20.
Now I want to basically work out the Sale Price as that is the unknown I am trying to figure out

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Luca for the support in pointing me in the right direction, I have come to a final solution of:

```
cost_price = 8.50 * 1.2
fee_3 = 2.90
fee_4 = 0.18

cost = cost_price + fee_3 + fee_4
sale_price = cost
fee_1 = sale_price * 0.2
fee_2 = (sale_price * 0.066) + 0.60

final_cost = fee_1 + fee_2 + cost

final_sale_price = final_cost / (1-0.081)
profit = final_sale_price - final_cost
print(final_sale_price, profit, purchase_price, final_cost)
```

Output:

> 19.155643564356435, 1.7431635643564363, 10.2, 17.41248

I hope this is of some use to someone other than me =)